# How to send data to corresponding region's instance server?

Tags: load-balancing, region, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Let's say I have three regions(eu,us,asia) that host the same app on the respective instance. I will register only one domain name for those same apps.

When a user requests from eu , I like to send data to eu region app server and vice versa.

Eg: user -> request -> example.com (from eu) -> send data to eu app

Eg: user -> request -> example.com (from us) -> send data to us app

Eg: user -> request -> example.com (from asia) -> send data to asia app

Can I set up like that by Load Balancer or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [OCI DNS and traffic management](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/DNS/home.htm) via [geolocation traffic steering policies](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/TrafficManagement/Tasks/trafficmanagement.htm#Managing_Traffic_Management_Steering_Policies). The steering policy should filter or prioritize DNS answers based on a query's [continent geokey](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/TrafficManagement/Reference/trafficmanagementgeo.htm#Continent_geokeys).

> Example of a POST /steeringPolicies request body using the ROUTE_BY_GEO template:
>
> ```
> {
>   "compartmentId": "ocid1...",
>   "displayName": "Geolocations mapped to answer pools",
>   "ttl": 30,
>   "healthCheckMonitorId": "ocid1...",
>   "template": "ROUTE_BY_GEO",
>   "answers": [
>     {
>       "name": "US Server 1",
>       "rtype": "A",
>       "rdata": "192.168.0.2",
>       "pool": "US"
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "US Server 2",
>       "rtype": "A",
>       "rdata": "192.168.0.3",
>       "pool": "US"
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "EU Server 1",
>       "rtype": "A",
>       "rdata": "192.168.0.4",
>       "pool": "EU"
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "EU Server 2",
>       "rtype": "A",
>       "rdata": "192.168.0.5",
>       "pool": "EU"
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "rest of world 1",
>       "rtype": "A",
>       "rdata": "203.0.113.2",
>       "pool": "Global"
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "rest of world 2",
>       "rtype": "A",
>       "rdata": "203.0.113.3",
>       "pool": "Global"
>     }
>   ],
>   "rules": [
>     {
>       "ruleType": "FILTER",
>       "defaultAnswerData": [
>         {
>           "answerCondition": "answer.isDisabled != true",
>           "shouldKeep": true
>         }
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "ruleType": "HEALTH"
>     },
>     {
>       "ruleType": "PRIORITY",
>       "cases": [
>         {
>           "caseCondition": "query.client.geoKey in (geoKey '6255149')",
>           "answerData": [
>             {
>               "answerCondition": "answer.pool == 'US'",
>               "value": 1
>             },
>             {
>               "answerCondition": "answer.pool == 'EU'",
>               "value": 2
>             },
>             {
>               "answerCondition": "answer.pool == 'Global'",
>               "value": 3
>             }
>           ]
>         },
>         {
>           "caseCondition": "query.client.geokey in (geokey '6255148')",
>           "answerData": [
>             {
>               "answerCondition": "answer.pool == 'EU'",
>               "value": 1
>             },
>             {
>               "answerCondition": "answer.pool == 'US'",
>               "value": 2
>             },
>             {
>               "answerCondition": "answer.pool == 'Global'",
>               "value": 3
>             }
>           ]
>         },
>         {
>           "answerData": [
>             {
>               "answerCondition": "answer.pool == 'Global'",
>               "value": 1
>             },
>             {
>               "answerCondition": "answer.pool == 'US'",
>               "value": 2
>             },
>             {
>               "answerCondition": "answer.pool == 'EU'",
>               "value": 3
>             }
>           ]
>         }
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "ruleType": "LIMIT",
>       "defaultCount": 1
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> -- [Traffic Management Steering Policies API Guide, Create Steering Policies Using Templates](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/TrafficManagement/Concepts/trafficmanagementapi.htm#Create_Steering_Policies_Using_Templates)

Comment: You save from my stressful days ! Thanks